# Solve $\dot{y}=A\sqrt{u(t) - y(t)},$ where $u(t) > y(t)>0,\;y(0)=y_0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the general nonlinear first-order ODE shown below.

$$ \dot{y}=A\sqrt{u(t) - y(t)} $$
$$ y(0)=y_0$$

where

- $A$ is a positive constant
- $u(t)$ is a given input function of time
- $u(t)>y(t)>0$

If $u(t)$ is a constant, then I can solve the ODE. However, a general solution is escaping me for the general $u(t)$.

**How would you approach solving this equation analytically?**

Comment: This can’t be solve analytically in general.

Comment: The transformation $2\sqrt{u(t)-y}=-w$ brings your equation to an Abel equation of the second kind with respect to $w(t)$.

Comment: $v^2 = u(t)-y(t)$ gets rid of the radical. The new differential equation turns into $2v\dot{v}+Av=\dot{u}$